# Кодировка JS в IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, кодировка

Есть XHTML-страница с XML декларацией

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

Страница не кириллице, с динамической информацией, отображается ок.
Также есть скрипт, подключаемый отдельным файлом:

```
<script src="resources/js/common.js" charset="utf-8"/>
```

И вот тут проблема. Информация на кириллице, получаемая из скрипта, отображается в некорректной кодировке. Собственно, charset прописывал, менял кодировку самого скрипта на UTF-8 и UTF-8 без BOM - ничего не помогло. В чем может быть причина и как фиксить? В остальных браузерах все ок.

Comment: А он у вас старой версии закеширован в браузере.

Comment: Я до этого через IE его не тестил, сейчас на всякий случай сбросил кэш - не помогло.

Comment: Если у вас apache, то первой строкой в .htaccess пишите `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: у меня Glassfish